# What should unseen data comply mathematically for reliable measure of generalisation (gap)?

Tags: machine-learning, out-of-sample

The way machine learning models validated for their generalisation performance, generalisation gap is used, see [Predicting the Generalization Gap in Deep Neural Networks](https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/07/predicting-generalization-gap-in-deep.html). This is essentially standard holdout method. Random splitting is a standard practice.  We take test set which was not used in model building granted as *unseen data*.

What should *unseen data* comply mathematically for reliable measure of generalisation (gap)? (at least from *statistical learning theory* perspective).

While, *unseen data* is open to interpretation: if it means outside the domain of training data ("completely out-of-sample"), then random splitting is not sufficient or reliable way of measuring generalisation, mathematical setting or tests that should be applied to *unseen data* would clarify this possible ambiguity.

Comment: There seems to be a partial answer to this question by a recent work from LeCun's team [Learning in High Dimension Always Amounts to Extrapolation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.09485). Detecting convex hull of the training set might be a good starting point.